# How can i make clean form button click run out of any event or condition?

Tags: c#

I have a form with some groupboxes that I put some textbox or combobox and other to get some information from user. I set Groupbox_Leave to check if its controls isn't empty for any groupbox. I have a button for clean the form out of the groupboxes.
The problem is when the user filled part of a groupbox and want to clean the form, he can't. Because groupbox_leave is run and say you should fill all field in this groupboxt to leave.
I want that the clean form button can click and run out of any condition and event.

How can I handle this problem?

**Update 1**

I need something like below:

```
public void Groupbox_leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(mouse click on clean_form_button)
  {
     clean_form_button_click(sender, e);
  }
  else
  {
     // check all controls in the GroupBox were filled
  }
}
```

but I don't know what code can I use insted mouse click on clean_form_button!

Comment: I want  when the user is in the groupbox, clean_form_button_click run before groupbox_leave

Answer (score 0):

So, If you have to do that, I'm not sure this event is the best way to do it. I would use `LostFocus` event instead of it. This event will wait till the user clicks or enters into another control to start its process.

Using this event, you could use the next code:

```
public void GroupBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button.Focused == true) 
    {
       clean_form_button_click(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
      // check all controls in the GroupBox were filled
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

You're right, GroupBox doesn't have any Focus event, so you will have to use your first proposal. I test this code. I don't know if it's exactly what you need but it works for me:

```
public void GroupBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button.Focused == true) 
    {
        clean_form_button_click(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        // check all controls in the GroupBox were filled
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want this.

Comment: I edited the answer because the old one was not helpfull. I you want to add som information about your issue, edit your question please.

Comment: I try to test your suggestion, but we don't have LostFocus event for GroupBox.